# How do you put the mouse cursor over the OPEN button on a JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, mouse-cursor

I'm trying to snap my mouse cursor over the approve button by default on a JFileChooser but I cannot find any examples anywhere where this has been done before. I have tried using hard coded x,y positions but this is useless when I run my application on a different pc. Any help would be appreciated, my code is as follows:

```
FileOpenDialog fileChooser = new FileOpenDialog(index);
fileChooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    }
});

// Need to snap mouse cursor to OPEN button here somehow or within overidden
// method of showOpenDialog???

int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(mainFrame);
System.out.println("Return Value is " + returnVal);

if (returnVal == FileOpenDialog.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    setFileIndex(index);
    setInputFile(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
}

class FileOpenDialog extends JFileChooser {

    public String fileName;
    public String dialogTitle;

    public FileOpenDialog(int index) {
        initComponent(index);
    }

    private void initComponent(int index) {
        setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

        CustomFileFilter myFilter = new CustomFileFilter();
        setFileFilter(myFilter);

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            setFileName("\\MelbCupHorses.txt");
            setDialogTitle("Please Choose Horses File");
            break;
        case 1:
            setFileName("\\MelbCupEntrants.txt");
            setDialogTitle("Please Choose Employees File");
            break;
        }

        System.out.println(getCurrentDirectory().toString() + fileName);

        File file = new File(getCurrentDirectory().toString() + fileName);
        setSelectedFile(file);
    }


    /**
     * @return the dialogTitle
    */
    @Override
    public String getDialogTitle() {
        return dialogTitle;
    }

    /**
     * @param dialogTitle the dialogTitle to set
    */
    @Override
    public void setDialogTitle(String dialogTitle) {
        this.dialogTitle = dialogTitle;
    }
}
```

Thanking you.

Comment: *"I'm trying to snap my mouse cursor over the approve button by default on a JFileChooser"* Why do that as opposed to simply ensuring it has focus?  And how exactly can the user use a `JFileChooser` in such a way as to never need to hit any button but one?  In that case, the `File` would need to be always the same file, and the chooser seems redundant.

Comment: I agree with @AndrewThompson and add, the default "approve" button is not only the `JRootPane`'s default button, but typically also has a keyboard mnemonic associated with it, allow the user two keyboard actions to trigger default approve button

Comment: I thought it would be nicer to "prompt" the user with a default filename, location and mouse over button option because it's a mouse driven application. I get what you're saying though, thankyou for your insight

Comment: @nufanme You'd be surprised how many user use the keyboard over the mouse even in GUIs.  For users use to the system, it's actually quicker.  I don't click the "Explorer" icon any more, I use [Window]+[E], as it's faster and easier, for example ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the modal state of the dialog, it can be a little tricky, but with the use of a `WindowListener` and [`java.awt.Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html), it can be achieved

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class FileChooserExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FileChooserExample();
    }

    public FileChooserExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                FileOpenDialog dialog = new FileOpenDialog(0);
                dialog.showOpenDialog(null);

            }
        });
    }

    class FileOpenDialog extends JFileChooser {

        public String fileName;
        public String dialogTitle;

        public FileOpenDialog(int index) {
            initComponent(index);
        }

        @Override
        protected JDialog createDialog(Component parent) throws HeadlessException {
            JDialog dialog = super.createDialog(parent);
            dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                    JDialog dialog = (JDialog) e.getWindow();
                    JButton button = dialog.getRootPane().getDefaultButton();
                    Point pos = button.getLocationOnScreen();
                    Dimension size = button.getSize();
                    pos.x += (size.width / 2);
                    pos.y += (size.height / 2);

                    try {
                        Robot bot = new Robot();
                        bot.mouseMove(pos.x, pos.y);
                    } catch (AWTException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            });
            return dialog;
        }

        private void initComponent(int index) {
            setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

            System.out.println(getCurrentDirectory().toString() + fileName);

            File file = new File(getCurrentDirectory().toString() + fileName);
            setSelectedFile(file);
        }

        /**
         * @return the dialogTitle
         */
        @Override
        public String getDialogTitle() {
            return dialogTitle;
        }

        /**
         * @param dialogTitle the dialogTitle to set
         */
        @Override
        public void setDialogTitle(String dialogTitle) {
            this.dialogTitle = dialogTitle;
        }
    }
}
```

The next question is...why are you messing with my mouse?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for @MadProgrammer but just lacked the experience to delve this deep into the JFileChooer. Awesome answer which I would upvote if I could :) And whose mouse is it really???

Comment: It's the users, arbitrarily moving is confusing to say the least.  I've tried software that automatically moves the mouse to default button of dialogs before...it lasted about 10 minutes before it became to frustrating...just saying...not mess with user expectations ;)

Comment: ok, yeah I can see how maybe that would get annoying. I suppose I'm just used to having this option set by default in Windows so I'm probably biased. Thanks again for your lightning fast responses and expertise. Any user complaints and I'll let you say "I told you so" LOL!

Comment: Every user is different ;)