# How can I automate the response on a Swing Dialog Box?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Given the simplest code possible:

```
//getDialogResponse() cannot be changed.
public static int getDialogResponse() {
    return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Make a really important choice.", "THE CHOICE", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] val = new int[1];
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {val[0] = getDialogResponse();});
    //TODO: The program itself presses the 'Yes' button.
    if(val[0] == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) System.out.println("Good Choice.");
    else System.out.println("Wise guy, huh?!");
}
```

`Robot` seems like a poor fit, since it needs to know the location of the newly created dialog box, and if it isn't in the same location every time, it won't work, so I need to know either how to get the location of the button itself, or I need to know a method that doesn't depend on the position of the newly created dialog box.

Also, I cannot change the `getDialogResponse()` code: that's an invariant.

So what can I do?

Comment: Why show the panel in the first place if the can't click?

Comment: @MariusK. It's for unit testing purposes. Normally the user *would* be able to click it, but I need a piece of code to automatically click the button for me so that the test can verify that the resulting behavior is correct.

Comment: Maybe this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730044/closing-a-dialog-created-by-joptionpane-showoptiondialog

Comment: @Massimo As I mentioned in the question, I don't have the option of altering `getDialogResponse()`, and the code in the question you linked requires me to do that.

Comment: I would separate program logic from GUI, à la MVC, and unit test the heck out of the model and control but not the view.

Comment: @Xirema, I was meaning the 2nd response, the one using 'JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();'

Comment: You could try using `Robot` to inject key events to trigger the button

Comment: [This example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134978/how-do-you-put-the-mouse-cursor-over-the-open-button-on-a-jfilechooser/24135173#24135173) "might" work

Answer (score 0):

[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) supports finding dialogs/buttons and clicking them in an automated way.  Perhaps it will help you.